# Limiting SUM to 30 records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created sum to calculate the positive and negative of a data table column. I am now trying to set a LIMIT on the query but I cant seem to get it working. Here is the query that I am wanting to LIMIT.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN label > 0 THEN label ELSE 0 END) POSITIVE_BALANCE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN label < 0 THEN label ELSE 0 END) NEGATIVE_BALANCE 
FROM units
```

Comment: You haven't used Limit keyword at all in your query.

Comment: try learning something from here https://bipp.io/sql-tutorial/basic-sql/sql-order-by-limit-clauses/ (small google help)

Comment: @nice_dev correct. Dont know where it goes... didnt work at the end of the query

Comment: Just add `limit 30` at the end

Comment: @nice_dev thats what I thought but doesnt work?

Comment: Ok, can you share a SQL fiddle? https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: That's correct.  In the context of the above SUM operations, the result contains 1 row per group and LIMIT restricts the number of groups in the result.  Since there is no GROUP BY clause, the result contains only one group.  You would need to limit the number of rows prior to the SUM operation OR with window functions, as part of the OVER clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jon Armstrong said, the LIMIT clause only limits the amount of results you get, not the amount of rows  you use to get those results (unless you group). For your case, you can first select the rows you want and then sum them.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN label > 0 THEN label ELSE 0 END) POSITIVE_BALANCE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN label < 0 THEN label ELSE 0 END) NEGATIVE_BALANCE
from (select label
      FROM units
      limit 30) temp
```

Comment: Absolute legend. thanks so much